# multiple inheritance destructor calling his own and parent destructor? c++

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-destructor

Hi I'm trying to create a derived class from a derived class.
But I don't know how to solve this memory problem.

Class C in below exmaple calls both his own destructor and the B-destructor.
But that's not what I want, since it messes up my memory.

Should I use another aproach or is there a solution to this?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};


class B : public A {
public:

    B() : A() {}
    virtual ~B() {std::cout << "B Destructor" << std::endl;}
};

class C : public B {

public:
    C() : B() {}
    ~C() {std::cout << "C Destructor" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {

    A *b = new B();
    A *c = new C();

    delete b;
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 ./a.out
 B Destructor
 C Destructor
 B Destructor
```

//edit
Sorry seems like I actually posted a working example.
Nevertheless in my real code (but I actually used the pattern from above example: I get the error

> labrob(5254,0x7fff77789000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe3dbc00030: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   Abort trap: 6

And when I remove the destructor of C I get a memory leak
this error actually only appears using the C-type Robot

so I have 3 kinds of robots which can be instantiated multiple times on runtime and are pushed into a list of robots.

which solve a maze on different threads

in the end I am deleting the robots from the list with an iterator

on valgrind it says am deallocating to much memory
so my thoughts the destructor call of both B and C are causing this.

in my main.cpp:

```
    // delete robots
    for (auto it = robots.begin(); it != robots.end(); ++it) {

        if(printSolution) std::cout << (*it)->solution() << std::endl;
        delete *it;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cs destructor has to call also Bs constructor, otherwise your memory will be messed up.... why do you want to prevent that? From your example it is not clear at all what will get messed up, actually nothing will get messed up here

Comment: If `B` is a parent of `C` then when `C` is destroyed then the `B` part of `C` also needs to be destroyed.

Comment: I mean you declared the destructor `virtual` yourself. You dont have to do this, but I would not suggest you to do so.

Comment: *Hi I'm trying to create a derived class from a derived class. But I don't know how to solve this memory problem.*  -- There is no memory problem in the code you posted.  Please post the actual code you say has memory problems.  C++ is doing the correct thing.

Comment: sorry, seems like I was too inaccurate and had a tunnel view on the destructor calls.. but I extended my post above.. but thanks already for all the answers @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @jcal Why are you showing us input code and print_usage?  It isn't necessary.  Just create 2 or 3 items in your Robot vector and test.  Second, if you commented out that entire code to set up and call threads, do you still get memory errors?  The bottom line is that you should post an [mcve], meaning we don't care about input routines, getopt(), etc.  Just a simple vector, call a function, destroy the items, error recreated.

Comment: And, guess what, B's destructor calls A's destructor! That's how C++ works, and that's a good thing.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Oh, also, this is not multiple inheritance. Multiple inheritance means that a class derives directly from two or more bases. So `class C : public B, public A {};` would be multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is that C++ is doing the right thing here.  If this messes up your memory, *you* are doing the wrong thing.  Unfortunately, without more context it is difficult to tell what wrong thing you are doing.

When `C` inherits from `B`, `~B()` should destroy memory owned by the `B` portion of `C`, and `~C()` should handle any memory that is part of `C`, but not part of `B`.